# Why Unicode is not used for file system reserved characters?

Tags: windows, filesystems, unicode

I'd really like to use characters like "?" in Windows for filenames. I understand why they are reserved, but why haven't they, or will they ever circumvent this by using unicode characters that look the same but (obviously) have different Unicode codes?

I think is entirely possible, but if not, why?

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason they aren't is because of the potential to cause confusion.  If you have a character that looks like a "?" but has a different unicode code - how will you tell the difference?

How would you explain it to someone?  "You can't have a question-mark in your filename, but you can have a thing-that-looks-like-a-question-mark-but-isn't, and to type it you only need to use this 5-key combination."?

Better (in my opinion) to exclude them completely and avoid mistakes.

Comment: A normal user shouldn't encounter that problem, programmers should. Programs like Windows Explorer would automaticaly use the lookalike intead the real "?". Other programs can tell a Windows API that certain field is for filenames so it replaces the characters with lookalikes. Copying text with lookalikes would replace them with the real ones. Most people are not programmers and never use wildcard characters.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then to use the unicode characters as the wildcards?  Less confusion for everyone else and no worrying about whether a particular program implements this strategy, and since programmers are already familiar with unicode, not such a big deal for them to use unicode chars for wildcards.

Comment: The problem is not because of lookalike characters but because `?` is a wildcard in Windows

Answer (score 3):

The characters that are not allowed in a file name are:

- `<` (less than)
- `>` (greater than)
- `:` (colon)
- `"` (double quote)
- `/` (forward slash)
- `\` (backslash)
- `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
- `?` (question mark)
- `*` (asterisk)

according to [Microsoft Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Is that what you were referring to?

The reason is probably because it would be too hard to deal with files with those characters in them in the old `command.com` shell, e.g. `?` also means any one character, `*` also means any file, etc.

Rather than teach everyone how to handle those special cases, they disallowed it, making it easier to script.

There wouldn't be Unicode equivalents for those characters, and if there was an equivalent, it still wouldn't solve that problem: the existing ASCII `?` and `*` would still have to work as wildcards, otherwise everyone would have to re-write their scripts.

Comment: Note that most of those restrictions are in the Windows API layer. The file system itself couldn't care less and in fact, NTFS can also support POSIX file name semantics.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following Unicode which looks similar to the original one without risk

They are valid as windows name:

- « ([U+00AB](http://unicode-table.com/en/00AB/)) instead of < (less than)
- » ([U+00BB](http://unicode-table.com/en/00BB/)) instead of > (greater than)
- ։ ([U+0589](http://unicode-table.com/en/0589/) or ÷ ([U+00F7](http://unicode-table.com/en/00F7/)) or ‡ ([U+2021](http://unicode-table.com/en/2021/))   instead of : (colon)
- “ ([U+201C](http://unicode-table.com/en/201C/)) instead of " (double quote)
- ⁄ ([U+2044](http://unicode-table.com/en/2044/)) insteaf of / (forward slash)
- ∖ ([U+2216](http://unicode-table.com/en/2216/)) or ＼ ([U+FF3C](http://unicode-table.com/en/FF3C/)) or 〵 ([U+3035](http://unicode-table.com/en/3035/)) instead of \ (backslash)
- ¦ ([U+00A6](http://unicode-table.com/en/00A6/)) instead of | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ‽ ([U+203D](http://unicode-table.com/en/203D/)) ⁇ ([U+2047](http://unicode-table.com/en/2047/)) ¿([U+00BF](http://unicode-table.com/en/00BF/)) instead of ? (question mark)
- ☀ ([U+2600](http://unicode-table.com/en/2600/)) instead of * (asterisk)

NB:
The [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/2216/) let you search character by description (like roman), the actual character and also give as reference others characters related (looking the same)

Please find below valid filename (copy & paste to try it; works under windows 7 with windows explorer and displays correctly, sorry cannot add screenshot).
You will notice that the look is different under windows than inside a browser (change of font)

unicode 一 ☀  ¦ »  ։∖ ‡〵 ÷╲    ‽ ⁇ ¿ ‰ ¢ π ∞ « ≈.txt

---

Couple of references

1. www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/copyright-symbol-ascii-code-184.html
2. http://www.theworldofstuff.com/characters/
3. http://unicode-table.com/en/#00A9
4. http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/altchrc-a.html
5. http://unicode-table.com/en/#enclosed-alphanumerics
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086375/what-character-to-use-to-put-an-item-at-the-end-of-an-alphabetic-list

NB: Windows is Posix compliant since 1980 (according to wikipedia) so it does comply to posix RFCs including the one specifying filenames
This [answer on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename) give broader context around RFC and which characters are allowed in filenames

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: The question says "will they ever circumvent this by using unicode characters that look the same". None of your replacements look the same. Several of them don't even display correctly. https://i.imgur.com/D6rRA2j.png

Comment: The OP is specifically asking about Windows. So talking about Unix and RFC is irrelevant.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with any random article about fixing Linux files system. And for your information we cannot close questions as duplicates of questions **on a different site**.

Comment: `‽` does **not** look like `?`. It looks completely different.

Comment: Any further discussion should be raised on [meta.su].

Answer (score 1):

You can use those characters now yourself. But I'm assuming you mean to have the operating system automatically transliterate between an ASCII question mark, for example, and a lookalike such as ﹖ (`SMALL QUESTION MARK` - UFE56). I really don't think that's satisfactory, especially since Linux and others, where the only invalid characters for filenames are slash (`/`) and null (ASCII 0), accept those characters readily.

Further reading:

- [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html):
  Control Characters (such as Newline), Leading Dashes, and Other Problems
- Wikipedia article on [Filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)