# Asterisk in Windows filename

Tags: windows, filenames

I'm trying to copy and paste the asterisk in a filename in Windows, but I got an error; I copied also the asterisk from charmap, but nothing to do.
Is there a symbol also similar to the asterisk that I can copy in a Windows' filename?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names Using illegal characters or even such as emoji etc are just a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: You cannot use asterisk as it has a special meaning in pretty much every operating system. You could use alternative unicode characters, though it depends on the font your system uses having those characters available: https://superuser.com/a/1128612/19943 My personal favourite instead of asterisk is "star" ★

Comment: Hello @Tetsujin if I copy these characters ˂ and ˃ similar to < and >, they work very well. For this reason maybe there is an equivalent asterisk character.

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk is a forbidden character in Windows file names and directories. If you want to make a safe choice and pick a symbol that would work across different operating systems, you could use a hyphen, an underscore, or a period — but note that you typically will not be able to start or end the file name or path with those symbols.

Technically you could use almost any standard Unicode character, other than characters that are reserved by Windows, but not all of them will work with other operating systems or programs.

Here is a list of the reserved characters on Windows:
`<` (less than)
`>` (greater than)
`:` (colon)
`"` (double quote)
`/` (forward slash)
`\` (backslash)
`|` (vertical bar or pipe)
`?` (question mark)
`*` (asterisk)

For more details specifically on Windows file name conventions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file